What explanation do ‘Anonymous Gospel’ proponents give for the first person portions of Acts?
I have heard supporters of the idea that the Gospels were only named long after the fact - such as Bart Ehrman - say that they were so named to pretend that they were written by an Apostle or the companion of an Apostle - when really they were no such thing .
How do they explain the first person portion of Acts where the original writer seems to be implying that he was a companion of an Apostle?

"How do they explain the first person portion of Acts …" — The book "Acts" isn't one of the four Gospels, so how is that relevant to the question?

@RayButterworth as answered on this site, that Acts and Luke have the same authorship is generally accepted. Of course, if there are people who try to salvage anonymity by splitting the books then that would be an answer.

"Acts and Luke have the same authorship" — Yes, but the question would be much better if it explicitly included such information rather than assuming all the readers know what you know.

@RayButterworth I want answers from people who know the answer such people don’t need me to mention that (and nor do people who are also curious about the same question) - nor do I want to shut off potential answers by insisting on a single authorship.

The purpose of these questions and answer is so that many people can learn, not only so that the person asking it gets an answer. When questions are worded in a way that many people can't understand, they no longer serve this purpose.

@RayButterworth Yes, I agree. I have voted for closure regarding 'clarity and detail'. If a useful edit is made I shall cancel my vote.
